# Adding to this script so that it runs on multiple sheets, not just the one sheet coded here

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the below script that runs on one Tab called Day 1. But I'd like it to run on multiple tabs, all called sequentially, Day 2, Day 3, etc. all the way to Day 31. Same criteria as Day 1, just a way to apply this script to all the tabs. But i'm a total noob at coding. Can you help? Thank you so much in advance.

````
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if( s.getName() == "Day 1") { //checks that we're on Day 1 or not
var r = s.getActiveCell();
if( r.getColumn() == 23 ) { //checks that the cell being edited is in column W
var nextCell = r.offset(0, 6);
if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //checks if the adjacent cell is empty or not?
nextCell.setValue(new Date());
   }
}
}```
````

Comment: Use `.getSheets()` instead of `.getActiveSheet()` as it returns an array of all sheets

Comment: Do I need to change the line ```if( s.getName() == "Day 1")``` to something else?

Comment: I changed it to .getSheets(), and it didn't return a timestamp. If I change back to .getActiveSheet() it does return a timestamp.

Comment: It returns an array, the first sheet will be `getSheets()[0]`, the second is `getSheets()[1]` Etc. you need to loop through them

Comment: Could you maybe specify what is the operation you want to replicate in all the sheets? Is the range modified the same for every sheet? Do you want to do the action in all the sheets called `Day X`?

Comment: I'm trying to auto add a timestamp in Column AC, when a person's name is entered in Column W. Really if any text is put in W, I'd like a timestamp to occur on same row, but column AC. Each tab (Day 1, Day 2, etc.) has a range W10:AC25, that is used to gather information on employees if they're late for work, etc. When we put an employee's name on, say W10, we need a record of when it was entered, which is the timestamp on AC10. As I said, there are 31 tabs, one for each day. I was hoping to create one script that that applied across all the tabs, rather than me putting a formula in each Day.

Answer (score 1):

So for your case what you need is the use of [`getSheets()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets). This method of the `Spreadsheet` class will return you a list of all the sheets inside said spreadsheet.

So imagine that you would like to modify the cell *A4* in every sheet of the spreadsheet.

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  const a1Notation = "A4";
  
  const sheets = ss.getSheets();
  
  for(let sheet of sheets){
    updateRange(sheet, a1Notation);
  }
}

function updateRange(sheet, a1Notation){
  sheet.getRange(a1Notation).setValue(Date.now())
}
```

Of course this could be expanded to fit your needs, maybe you only want to modify the sheets that fit a regular expression or change the range depending on the sheet.